# Open coloring axiom vs. CH

Tags: set-theory, continuum-hypothesis

Is there a simple, direct proof that the open coloring axiom contradicts CH (straight from the definitions, no machinery allowed)? The separable metric spaces version of OCA, if that helps.

Edit: probably it wasn't clear what I was asking. Let's say, hypothetically, that I'm writing a book on forcing that is meant to be as elementary and readable as possible. I've just introduced OCA and I have half a page to show the reader that it contradicts CH. Can I do this without quoting external theorems?

Comment: When you say OCA, I suppose you mean the one from Todorcevic's work, and not the one from the Abraham-Rubin-Shelah paper, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean Todorcevic's axiom.

Answer (score 10):

Here are two suggestions, whether they follow your instructions of "no machinery allowed", I will leave to you.

The following seems fairly direct to me, and I would think is the "standard" answer to your question:

First, partially order $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ by *eventual domination*: $f<g$ iff $f(n)<g(n)$ for all $n$ large enough.

If $X\subseteq\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ is unbounded and countably directed, then there are $f\ne g$ in $X$ such that $f(n)\le g(n)$ for *all* $n$. This is proved as Lemma 0.7 in Todorcevic's **Partition problems in topology**.

From this it follows that under $\mathsf{OCA}$, any subset of $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ of size $\aleph_1$ is bounded. (For example, this follows from Proposition 8.4.(c) and the proof of Theorem 3.5 in Todorcevic's book.)

(Refining this argument (eventually) gives us that $\mathsf{OCA}$ implies that ${\mathfrak b}=\aleph_2$.) The only technical tool this uses is the notion of *oscillation*, and what is needed can be developed directly in the proof of the statements above.

A different approach goes by building on Proposition 8.4.(c) directly: $\mathsf{OCA}$ implies that if $X,Y$ are uncountable sets of reals, then there is an uncountable subset of $X$ and a strictly increasing map of this subset into $Y$. This easily clashes with $\mathsf{CH}$, for example, using the results of Sierpiński on [*Sur un problème concernant les types de dimensions*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm19/fm1919.pdf).

Comment: (I expect there are more elegant/direct ways of verifying the claim in the fifth paragraph than the 8.4-3.5 route I suggest, but I tried to stay as close to Stevo's book as possible, to avoid sneaking in machinery through additional developments.)

Comment: I'm afraid this is exactly the sort of thing I didn't have in mind --- quoting a consequence X of OCA and then showing that X contradicts CH. I would only consider this a "direct" proof if you include the proof that OCA implies X --- which in your case makes your answer not so simple ...

Comment: (I guess I do not understand what you mean, since the proofs are direct implications that are spelled out in good amount of detail in the book.)

Comment: Yes, well, every complete proof is a "direct implication", isn't it?

Comment: I think you understand perfectly well what I mean, but for example: use CH to directly construct, as simply as possible, a separable metric space together with an open coloring that violates OCA.

Comment: (I see that these are arguments that take more than one step. Perhaps that's what you mean, as in spite of your expectations, I really don't understand you otherwise, Nik. But that's OK. Maybe others will suggest other nice applications of $\mathsf{OCA}$.)

Comment: Although I agree with Andres (thanks for referring this proof and the book), maybe you can settle with a "simpler" axiom i.e. SOCA and read another proof in the new book by Kunen (in Lemma V.6.10 he shows that SOCA implies no weakly Luzin set, which of course contradicts CH).

Comment: Here is an inclusive version of Andres' answer: http://blog.assafrinot.com/?p=3243

Comment: @Assaf: thank you for the detailed proof. This is essentially the argument I was already using in my book when I asked the question. I guess the consensus is that it is the most direct proof that OCA $\to$ $\neg\,$CH, although I still wonder if anyone has seriously tried to directly construct a counterexample to OCA using CH.

Comment: Incidentally, your proof of "Alternative 2" is not correct --- you only have $\{n < \omega: f_\alpha(n) > f_\beta(n)\} = \emptyset$. I noticed the same error in Velickovic's paper. I don't have access to Todorcevic's book at the moment, I wonder if the error tracks back to it?

Comment: Thanks, Assaf! @NikWeaver Any chance I could get a copy of a draft of your book when you feel it is appropriate?

Comment: @Andres: Sure, I will send you a copy of the proofs when I get them.

Comment: @Eran: What "new book by Kunen" are you referring to? The 2011 edition of his popular book Set Theory?

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the same approach as Kunen in his book "Set Theory" (2011). In section V.6 he work with $SOCA$ (a weakening of $OCA_{T}$ that only ask for the existance of one of the homogeneous subsets, not for a covering).

In approximately two pages (364-366) he presents $SOCA$ and shows that the axiom implies $\neg CH$. The way he do it is with weakly Luzin sets.

His proof work as follows:

1) Define a set in ${R}^{n}$ ($R$ is the reals) as skinny iff the set of directions is not dense in the unit sphere.

2) Defines a weakly Luzin as a set whose all uncountable subsets are not skinny.

3) Define  $A$ as an $\epsilon$-directed set iff there is a point in the unit sphere such that all the directions of $A$ have an angle at most of $\epsilon$ to that point.

4) Notice that every $\epsilon$-directed set is skinny.

5) Using induction and compactness show that $SOCA$ implies that every set is contains an $\epsilon$-directed set.

I was a litle vague because I left the reference. I can try to be more precise with definitions and proofs if needed.

Comment: Another option is using a 2-entangled set of size $\aleph_{1}$ (the definition of entangled set contradicts $SOCA$), and it is know that there always exists an entangled set of size continuum (so $CH$ contradicts $SOCA$). I'm not sure if the construction of the set is short or not.